# Unable to build image using gradle bootBuildImage in offline environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build image on offline environment using `paketobuildpacks/builder:base` and `paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb` image. I am running a [demo spring-boot project](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.1.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=devtools,lombok,configuration-processor,webflux,flapdoodle-mongo) that I created via http://start.spring.io/

So this is the command I'm using to build the image

`gradle clean build bootBuildImage`

On my machine that has internet connection, everything works fine, and I'm able to build the image successfully. However, when I bring the same project over to my offline environment and tried to do the same, it throws me some error.

The only difference is that I need to configure this in my offline environment (build.gradle)

```
bootBuildImage {
  builder = "myprivateartifactory/paketobuildpacks/builder:base",
  runImage = "myprivateartifactory/paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb"
}
```

The following is ran with `--debug` enabled - `gradle clean build bootBuildImage --debug`

```
Gradle Test Executor 6 finished executing tests.

> Task :test
Finished generating test XML results (0.008 secs) into: C:\Users\joseph\Desktop\demo (9)\demo\build\test-results\test
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.004 secs) into: C:\Users\joseph\Desktop\demo (9)\demo\build\reports\tests\test
:test (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 2.708 secs.
:check (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) started.

> Task :check
Skipping task ':check' as it has no actions.
:check (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:build (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) started.

> Task :build
Skipping task ':build' as it has no actions.
:build (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:bootBuildImage (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) started.

> Task :bootBuildImage
Caching disabled for task ':bootBuildImage' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':bootBuildImage' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Building image 'docker.io/library/demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

 > Pulling builder image 'cr.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' ..................................................
 > Pulled builder image 'cr.io/paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:dfbd2831033f37161f5027dfa46d5a658b29a3302c33aaf0219160a05fe5c12e'

> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED
:bootBuildImage (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 2.298 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> No 'io.buildpacks.builder.metadata' label found in image config labels 'io.buildpacks.stack.description,io.buildpacks.stack.distro.name,io.buildpacks.stack.distro.version,io.buildpacks.stack.homepage,io.buildpacks.stack.id,io.buildpacks.stack.maintainer,io.buildpacks.stack.metadata,io.buildpacks.stack.mixins,io.buildpacks.stack.released'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
```

Setup:

spring-boot 2.4.1 / gradle 6.7.1

What am I doing wrong? If more information is required, please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336624/building-docker-image-with-spring-boot-2-4-1-failes-with-missing-io-buildpacks might be related.

Comment: You might be right.. seem related

Comment: I'm the one who added the question I linked to. I upvoted your question to attract more attention to it. Feel free to do the same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336624/building-docker-image-with-spring-boot-2-4-1-failes-with-missing-io-buildpacks :) Thanks!

Comment: In the interest of avoiding duplicate support, there is an issue in the Spring Boot issue tracker as well where this is discussed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24641

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of the newly created issue. Will follow that issue.

Comment: The labels on the builder image in your private Artifactory are incorrect. Specifically, the `io.buildpacks.builder.metadata` label is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [spring-boot#24641](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24641) for more discussion. In short, the reason for the error mentioned above was that the wrong image was used.